# Discord.py Embed not sending

Tags: python, discord.py

I have this Cog, but it's not sending the embed, I even tried with embeds, but its only sending the first text and I'm not sure why.

```
from discord.ext import commands 

class HelpCommand(commands.Cog):
def __init__(self, client):
    self.client = client

@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_ready(self):
    print("Test Ready")

@commands.command(aliases=["h"])
async def command(self, ctx):
    await ctx.send(f'Please wait')
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Help for the bot",
                          description="", color=discord.Colour.purple())
    embed.set_footer(icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url,
                     text=f"Requested by {ctx.author.name}")
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
async def setup(client):
    await client.add_cog(HelpCommand(client))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be getting an error for this so you probably didn't configure logging properly, but `avatar_url` was removed in 2.0.

Migration guide: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/migrating.html#asset-redesign-and-changes

> Member.avatar_url (replaced by [Member.avatar](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Member.avatar))
>
> - **this new attribute may now be `None`**

This now returns an [`Asset`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Asset), and if you look at the docs for that you'll see that it has a [`url`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Asset.url) attribute. Note that you won't be able to access it if the avatar is `None`, so you'll have to check that first.

Comment: nevermind me, it was this haha I forgot to put "import discord" I only left by accident "from discord.ext import commands" and forgot the other, at the top, thanks for the logging tip, after I setup it it showed me the error